# What a information security help desk looks like

Tags: iso27001

ISO 27001 A.16 is talking about handling information security incidents and events and about the point of contact to which such events should be reported.

I'm wondering how in real life and real companies this is implemented.

I know how the handling of IT incidents looks like - there usually is IT ServiceDesk where the IT incidents are being reported.

But how this looks like when it's about information security?

Is there a parallel ServiceDesk/HelpDesk which is working only with information security or is the IT ServiceDesk also getting the events related to Information security (because information security is not only IT related)?

A few examples from the real world could help me to get the picture.

Answer (score 1):

What you are asking about is generally referred to as a Security Operations Center (SOC pronounced as "sock").  In this place Tier 1 security analysts review security incidents as they come in to determine if they are false positives or if they should be escalated to Tier 2 analysts/engineers.  If not a false positive they will generally write up a summary of the incident and escalate to tier 2.  Tier 2 will investigate and determine if the event is a false positive and or if it needs to be escalated to Incident Response (see below) or tier 3 for further analysis.  The exact breakdown of work between the tiers differs by organization but usually there are 3 tiers.  Some of this can be provided on-prem and some of it farmed out to a Managed Security Service Provider (MSSP).

The size of the organization and the maturity of their security team determines how the SOC looks (if they have one at all).  In some smaller/less mature organizations Security tasks are handled by the IT help/service desk.  The SOC is the preferred model and should involve plenty of overlap with the Network and IT/Admin teams as proper configuration by these teams is the backbone of security.

Furthermore in mature organizations there should be a separate incident response (IR) team which has business context and Administrative insight/access to hunt down and remediate any issues escalated by the SOC.

Additionally, or as part of the IR, team there should be a digital forensics team to escalate investigations that appear to be of a serious nature.

Finally there is a Huge Wealth of information on the web about this topic so look around and do plenty of reading.  You kind of only get one chance to build a SOC so build it right.

Comment: Just to add, as part of IR/DR, they should be documented point of contacts for each division or "zone" of the company so they can be reached upon incident. Many companies have a rotating "on call" for IT and Sec departments.